# Is there a way to make multiple insertions on the same list?

Tags: python, list, insert

This might sound like a dumb question, but I've been stumped on this for the last few hours.

The situation is as follows: I have a list of strings and I would like to do multiple insertions on it. That is, if I iterate through the list, and the element at index i in the list meets a certain condition, I want to add another element at position i+1. All fine and dandy so far, but whatever I tried I would always end up breaking the indexing because the length of the list of strings would change. I tried something similar to the code bellow, but that doesn't treat all elements from the list:

```
for i in range(3, len(list_of_strings)):
    if condition:
        list_of_strings[i].insert(i+1, 'Found a loop in function.\n\n')
    else:
        list_of_strings[i].insert(i+1, 'Found a backjump in function.\n\n')
```

If the above explanation is too hard to understand refer to this problem which can also lead to the solution I would like. Given a list of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, is there a way to insert 0 after the even numbers and 1 after the odd numbers in the same list?

Input: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
Output: `[1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 5, 1, 6, 0]`

Observations: Do not make a copy of the list, just iterate through the list given as input and modify it accordingly.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
i = 3
while i < len(list_of_strings) - 1:
    if condition:
        list_of_strings[i].insert(i + 1, 'Found a loop in function.\n\n')
    else:
        list_of_strings[i].insert(i + 1, 'Found a backjump in function.\n\n')
```

Alternatively, you could also just append each item in the first array to a new array. Then, even if you append a new conditional item, then it wont interfere with the original array.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion. I made a new array and append each item to the new array plus the extra item and return that. Omg, I feel so dumb now, I've been stuck on this for 2 hours or more now.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `for` loop, try using `while`.

```
i = 3
while True:
    if i + 1 == len(list_of_strings):
        break 
    elif condition:
        list_of_strings[i].insert(i+1, 'Found a loop in function.\n\n')
    else:
        list_of_strings[i].insert(i+1, 'Found a backjump in function.\n\n')
    i += 1
```

Comment: I was thinking of that too, but I think I missed the condition of

`if i + 1 == len(list_of_strings):
        break `
Either way, I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should change this:

```
list_of_strings[i].insert(i+1, 'Found a loop in function.\n\n')
```

to this:

```
list_of_strings.insert(i+1, 'Found a loop in function.\n\n')
```

Since you already specify the index of the insertion as the first argument of `insert()` so now you're doing that twice.

`i` will always increment in steps of 1 because of the for loop. But you want increment it with a variable amount so consider using another counter e.g. `j` like this:

```
j = 0
for i in range(3, len(list_of_strings)):
    if condition:
        list_of_strings.insert(j+1, 'Found a loop in function.\n\n')
        j += 1
    else:
        list_of_strings.insert(j+1, 'Found a backjump in function.\n\n')
        j += 1
    j += 1
```

Note that in your example you always increment by 2 because of the if-else, you will always insert something so you can just change your `for-loop` to:

```
for i in range(3, len(list_of_strings), 2):
```

And just use the method you suggested.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your input because I missed the flaw in my code where it increments by 2. In the end I found the solution, I commented what I did on the answer I marked with the green check. I'm sorry if I wasted your time on such a trivial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting into the same list you are iterating over has the problem of your target indices changing as you modify the list. A simpler solution would be to create a *new* list.

```
def add_elements(old_list):
    for x in old_list:
        yield x
        yield x % 2
```

Then

```
>>> list(add_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6))
[1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 5, 1, 6, 0]
```

There's also no need to define `add_elements` explicitly; it's essentially a special case of zipping two sequences and then flattening the result.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(L, (x%2 for x in L))))
[1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 5, 1, 6, 0]
```

The generator expression `(x%2 for x in L)` produces a sequence of 1s and 0s to insert into the original list `L`. `zip` pairs each element with the 1 or 0 that should follow it: `[(1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 0), ...]` `chain.from_iterable` just yields elements from each tuple in order as it iterates over the list.

Comment: I did that in the end, yes. Now I feel dumb for not getting that idea sooner, I've been stuck on this for about 2 hours now.